# SQLanywhere working console but not on localhost with PHP

Tags: php, apache, sqlanywhere

I have a linux setup (cent os), which i installed Sqlanywhere 12 perfectly, everything works well when I use the console with the PHP module on. I can access the database using php files ...

The only thing is I need to force the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in console to make it works.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then it works perfectly

But now I need to make it work also through simple request using the browser (for example test.php). Keeps telling me the connection failed to the database.

I'm wondering if it's due to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH not exported to the htppd service, I tried several things without any success (httpd.conf file, script, ..)

Sqlanywhere is working well, all the .so files are there, server is running, ...

I guess it's a small config somewhere i'm missing

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the following line

. /opt/sqlanywhere12/bin64/sa_config.sh

into the file /etc/init.d/httpd

That should work.